# Impletentación del Algoritmo de Dijkstra en C#

Tags: c#

Algoritmo de Dijkstra implementado en lenguaje de programación C#

Comment: Christian A Burbano Hernández que as intentado o investigado ??

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Christian A Burbano , te invito a realizar el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento básico del sitio. Con respecto a la realización de preguntas que estas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas excelentes respuestas, **es muy importante leer [ask]** en base a este documento debes modificar tu pregunta, es recomendable agregar lo que has intentado e investigado, saludos!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Tengo uno en Java pero encontré este en C#, te puede servir
Está implementado con arreglos, el mío en Java lo tengo de ambas maneras, en 
matrices y con listas.

```
private static int MinimumDistance(int[] distance, bool[] 
   shortestPathTreeSet, int verticesCount)
 {
    int min = int.MaxValue;
    int minIndex = 0;

for (int v = 0; v < verticesCount; ++v)
{
    if (shortestPathTreeSet[v] == false && distance[v] <= min)
    {
        min = distance[v];
        minIndex = v;
    }
}

return minIndex;
```

}

```
private static void Print(int[] distance, int verticesCount)
  {
   Console.WriteLine("Vertex    Distance from source");

for (int i = 0; i < verticesCount; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine("{0}\t  {1}", i, distance[i]);
```

}

```
public static void Dijkstra(int[,] graph, int source, int verticesCount)
 {
   int[] distance = new int[verticesCount];
   bool[] shortestPathTreeSet = new bool[verticesCount];

for (int i = 0; i < verticesCount; ++i)
{
    distance[i] = int.MaxValue;
    shortestPathTreeSet[i] = false;
}

distance[source] = 0;

for (int count = 0; count < verticesCount - 1; ++count)
{
    int u = MinimumDistance(distance, shortestPathTreeSet, verticesCount);
    shortestPathTreeSet[u] = true;

    for (int v = 0; v < verticesCount; ++v)
        if (!shortestPathTreeSet[v] && Convert.ToBoolean(graph[u, v]) && distance[u] != int.MaxValue && distance[u] + graph[u, v] < distance[v])
            distance[v] = distance[u] + graph[u, v];
}

Print(distance, verticesCount);
```

}

Comment: Probaste el Codigo?? no solo es copiar y pegar el Codigo que encuentras..  Christian A Burbano Hernández que as intentado o investigado ??

Comment: -1. Por favor evita responder preguntas de baja calidad donde el OP no muestra ninguna línea de código de lo que ha intentado.